# Calculating simple daily returns with a for loop in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate simple daily returns (x_t - x_t-1 / x_t-1) with a for loop, but I can't manage it.

Let's assume we have the following close prices of a stock.

```
x <- c(100, 101, 102, 100, 101, 102)
```

My loop idea is:

```
returns <- function(x){
n <- length(x)
daily.returns <- numeric(n-1)
for(i in 1:(n-1)){ 
daily.returns[i] <- (x[i+1]-x[i])/x[i]
return(daily.returns)
}
}
```

As a result, R calculates the first return correctly, but I get 0s otherwise.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As both Norman Matloff and Hadley Wichkam in their books on R (the art of R programming and advanced R) have put up that *given that R is vectorised, loops in R are mostly avoidable*.  This can be easily done without loops as

```
x <- c(100, 101, 102, 100, 101, 102)

daily_ret <- c(NA, (x[-1] - x[-length(x)])/x[-length(x)])

[1]          NA  0.01000000  0.00990099 -0.01960784  0.01000000  0.00990099
```

Comment: Or, we can do `tail(x,-1)/head(x,-1)-1`

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Yeah, that looks short and elegant.  Thanks, I will keep that in mind too.  By the way I am still in awe and wow after seeing `embed`  :)

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of tidyverse might be more elegant than a loop :

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- data.frame(value=c(100, 101, 102, 100, 101, 102))

return <- x %>%
  mutate(daily_return = (x-lag(x))/lag(x))
```

If you really want a for loop :

```
x <- c(100, 101, 102, 100, 101, 102)
return <- numeric()

for(i in 1:length(x)) {
  return[i] <- (x[i] - x[i-1]) / x[i-1]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short solution using `map_dbl`, which is much more concise than using a loop:

```
library(tidyverse)
returns <- map_dbl(2:length(x), ~ (x[.] - x[.-1])/x[.-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `embed` like below

```
with(
  data.frame(embed(x,2)),
  X1/X2-1
)
```

which gives

```
[1]  0.01000000  0.00990099 -0.01960784  0.01000000  0.00990099
```

Comment: Seen this `embed` first time.  Thanks for sharing :)